# Match xml element by tag and id in RegEx

Tags: c#, regex

#### I cannot parse the xml because at this stage it is invalid and will not parse.

How would I match a simple xml element (with the id) like so:

```
<g id="crop"></g>
```

Using a regular expression?

Thanks

Comment: Why with a regex? Use Xml tools for Xml.

Comment: Yes but in this case I would like to use regular expression

Comment: I cannot parse the xml because at this stage it is invalid and will not parse. This is why I am looking for RegEx.

Comment: "Would like to" is nonsense, a waste of everybody's time. Maybe you need to but then this sample is probably too simple, any RegEx solution will probably not scale very well.

Comment: Maybe better to post how/why it is invalid and ask how to repair it.

Comment: @codemonkey an invalid xml can be in many forms, I don't think you can find *magic* regex to fix all of them. How about posting some sample of broken xmls

Comment: Is the element guaranteed to be empty (as in your example)?  Or it can contain arbitrary, possibly-invalid XML?

Comment: the element (g) will always contain more elements.

Comment: You're unlikely to get an answer that avoids [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/). Note that Html is Xml in this context.

Comment: As mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/82682) you CAN'T parse XML using regex. You just can't. Period.

Answer (score 4):

At the risk of a downvote... How about using the right tool for the job?

```
var xmlStr = "<g id=\"crop\"></g>";
var att = XElement.Parse(xmlStr).Attribute("id");
var id = (string)att;
```

Comment: This is the right tool for the job but in my circumstance I cannot use it as the xml will not parse. I need to fix the xml first before I put it through a parser.

Comment: ...although I've found myself in exactly the same situation... discogs, I'm looking at you!